# Git error 400 when doing push

Tags: git, bash, github, terminal

When I do a `git push` I come up with this error:

> error: The requested URL returned error: 400 while accessing
>   https://github.com/nathandunn97/SchoolAdvisor.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
>   fatal: HTTP request failed

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and my git version is 1.8.1.2.

Comment: Okay, so a 400 error means the resource at that URL wasn't found. Are you sure that https://github.com/nathandunn97/SchoolAdvisor.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack is the right URL?

Comment: almost certain, I've already pushed files yesterday using the same laptop

Comment: Is the problem machine specific? Have you tried it on any other machines?

Comment: I think it could be, I haven't changed anything to do with git on my system though so I don't see why it would do this

Comment: No worries, I needed to start Apache for a push to take place!

Comment: @NathanDunn - would you please elaborate your reference to starting Apache for a push to take place?

Answer (score 5):

I has something similar to this on an internally hosted git repository (so I am not 100% sure it will fix your problem on github). "Git pull" worked fine, but "git push" gave me:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 400 while accessing http://10.3.231.11/fisheye/git/myrep.git/info/refs
```

What worked for me was going into.git/config, and changing the url to include my username in the url:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = http://username@10.3.231.11/fisheye/git/myrep.git
```

It then asked for a password after the push command, then pushed the files successfully.

Comment: Your comment made me open the config in 'sublime text' - showing me strange ESC markings behind the URLs. After removing them, it all worked again. Thanks!

Comment: In my case there was a whitespace behind the URL. After removing that whitespace it worked again. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

When you do a push with https you might need to write your password every time.
generate ssh keys for git hub

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

and then update your config file to the ssh url and you should be able to push your content.

Comment: Can the downvoter maybe explain why this is wrong? I am experiencing a similar problem, and there is no answer at the moment.